# Experiment: Can a JavaScript instance be a constructor itself & have its own set of instances?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, prototype

```
let bar;
function foo(){
  this.x=x;
  this.y=y;
}
bar=new foo(1,2);
/*Since all functions in javascript are objects. 
Why can't an instance an object be a constructor itself?*/
!function bar(a,b){
  this.a=a;
  this.b=b;
}(); // (1)
let bar1=new bar(3,4);
console.log(bar1.a);
```

(1): Using a named IIFE, can bar be an instance and a constructor at the same time?

It's just a fun trick to exploit the language's freedom to see if it is a possibility, any other ways of doing this?

Comment: your code will throw an error (redeclaration of `let bar`) - so, clearly you can't do that

Comment: Then how about using a named function expression such as ```(function bar(a,b){this.a=a, this b=b}());```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for a constructor-function-returning function:

```
function makeBar(x, y) {
  function Bar(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = y + b;
  }
  Bar.x = x;
  return Bar;
}

var Bar1 = makeBar("bar1", 2);
console.log(Bar1.x); // "bar1"
var myBar1 = new Bar1(1, 2); // Bar { a: 1, b: 4 }
console.log(myBar1 instanceof Bar1); // true

var Bar2 = makeBar("bar2", 0);
var myBar2 = new Bar2(3, 3); // Bar { a: 3, b: 3 }
console.log(myBar2 instanceof Bar1); // false
```

To make `makeBar` not a factory function but a constructor with a working prototype, you'd have to use

```
function Foo(x, y) {
  function Bar(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = y + b;
  }
  Object.setPrototypeOf(Bar, Foo.prototype);
  Bar.x = x;
  return Bar;
}
Foo.prototype.log = function() {
  console.log("I'm "+this.name);
};

var Bar = new Foo("bar", 2);
Bar.log();
console.log(Bar instanceof Foo); // true
var myBar = new Bar(1, 2);
console.log(myBar instanceof Bar); // true
```

Comment: This is partially accurate, here all instances of Foo will return Bar, ```var myFoo=new Foo(1,2);``` does``` myFoo.y===Bar.y```return true? Is myFoo pointing to a new private data ```y``` of ```Bar``` constructor or is it an instance property of ```Foo```

Comment: @PranavRaykar Every `Foo` call will return a new `Bar`. You can see that `Bar1 !== Bar2`. `x` is an instance property on all `Foo` "instaces", like `a` and `b` are properties of the `Bar` instances. `y` is a private closure variable (to demonstrate that the different `Bar`s do different things - otherwise the exercise would've been pointless).

Answer (score 1):

> Can a JavaScript instance be a constructor itself & have its own set of instances?

Sure, a *function* is an instance of `Function` and a *constructor* is a *function*.

So you can just have

```js
const instance1 = new Function("a", "this.a = a;");
const instance2 = new instance1("foo");
console.log(instance2.a); // "foo"
```

If you need `instance1` to be more than a raw Function, you can even extend this constructor:

```js
class MyFunc extends Function {
  doSomethingMore(){ console.log("I'm doing more"); }
}
const instance1 = new MyFunc("a", "this.a = a;");
instance1.doSomethingMore();
const instance2 = new instance1("foo");
console.log(instance2.a); // "foo"
```

But I can't see a clear reason why you'd ever want to do that...

*(Note that dynamically creating a function via the `Function` constructor is generally less "performant" than at parse time through function expression or statement.)*

Answer (score 0):

In your code, since `bar` is declared with `let`, it can't be re-declared as a function declaration in the same scope.

If you wanted to do this, you could have `foo` explicitly return a function, which could then be called with `new`:

```js
function foo(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  return function bar(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  };
}
const bar = new foo(1, 2);
const bar1 = new bar(3, 4);
console.log(bar1.a);
```

Comment: But here bar is an instance property of foo, it's not an instance of foo

Comment: `bar` is *not* an instance property of `foo` - `foo` returns the `bar` constructor.

Comment: So that's not what I wanted, so an superInstance can never itself be constructor, right?